# Tracking Area 51 site stats. How are we doing?

Tags: discussion

Area 51 provides a [snapshot of site stats](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58150/arduino) averaged over a two week period. How are our stats changing and progressing over time?

---

Moderators have aggregated analytics available to them via the mod tools. Such data is not available to users. The Area 51 page provides the data at the *current time* instant but does not show the trend over time. Are the numbers going up or down? By how much?

This post attempts to keep track of the data at different times, thereby providing a general idea of the site's growth. See similar efforts going on at other sites:

- https://productivity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/210/4252
- https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/q/56
- https://martialarts.meta.stackexchange.com/q/316

The point of this post is **not to compare** us to any other site, and nor to provide an analysis of the numbers (for now). It is *too* early to start analysing numbers.

Comment: A better question would be: how could we improve the current situation which is not very good regarding the number of questions daily (which seems even lower currently, I would say 3 questions/day the past few days)?

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Feel free to update this post every 2-3 weeks. Do not remove any of the earlier images.</sub>

### 22 Days

[image]

*[(Full Sized Photo Here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4HNs.png)*

### 48 Days

[image]

*[(Full Sized Photo Here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqPEt.png)*

### 102 Days

[image]

Comment: Why did you make two different answers?

Comment: Merging both posts may not ease time comparison (that would be mixing graphs)

Comment: @Ricardo Thanks for [this.](http://meta.arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/79/provisional-community-moderator-nominations#comment239_105) I have been told that a few times over the past 3-4 years, but I find it somewhat hard to internalize.

Comment: No problem! But it's really up to you. The alternative (that you seem to prefer) is to just get the job done and let your reputation speak for itself :) That's even better. So relax and be yourself.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Feel free to update this post every 2-3 weeks.</sub>

#### CSV Table

```
Day  Questions/Day  AnswerPercentage  TotalUsers  UsersWith200Rep  AnswerRatio  Visits/Day
 22            5.1                95         504               33          2.3         240
 48            5.2                94         878               67          2.2         403
102            5.9                89        1565               55          1.9         577
144            4.9                87        2025               60          1.9         981
```

**Note:** `UsersWith200Rep` is the *estimated* value, on days 30-90.

Comment: Huh, interesting idea... I may log this data (scrap it from the A51 page) so it's easier to keep track of.

Comment: @hichris123 How about maintaining it on Github with code (and here)? That way it can be available to everybody. Once we have enough data points, we can add plots to the repo (and here) as well.

Comment: Good idea; I can post the code... how do we add plots to the repo?

Comment: @hichris I will handle that part. We will need a few data points before we can do that.